# Can't add Marker on Google maps Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have tried numerous variations but none display the Marker on the map. Could anyone help, please?

```
</script>
  <script>
  function initialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.51697, -0.14650);
      var myOptions = {
          zoom: 16,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions);
  }

  // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.51697, -0.14650),
    map: map,
    title:"HERE"
});

// To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
marker.setMap(map);
  </script>
```

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons why the marker doesn't show up:

1. The `map` variable is local inside the `initialize` function, so you can't reach it from code outside the function.
2. The `initialize` function is called from the load event, so you try to add the marker to the map before it exists.

Add the marker to the map inside the `initialize` function. There you have access to the variable, and the map is already created when you add the marker.

If you need to access the map outside the `initialize` function, declare the variable `map` outside the function.